# Google Maps on Android: tileOverlay is not working

Tags: android, google-maps, tile

I try to add a TileOverlay to my Google Map on Android. The following Code does not work. No overlay is shown, non of the (Test-)Toasts are fired.

```
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    //mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
    mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
    LatLng foo = new LatLng(50, 12);
    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(foo, 15));
    TileProvider tileProvider = new UrlTileProvider(256, 256) {
        @Override
        public URL getTileUrl(int x, int y, int zoom) {
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Test1.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            /* Define the URL pattern for the tile images */
            String s = String.format("https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png",
                    zoom, x, y);

            if (!checkTileExists(x, y, zoom)) {
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Tile does not exist.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return null;
            }

            try {
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return new URL(s);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                throw new AssertionError(e);
            }
        }

        private boolean checkTileExists(int x, int y, int zoom) {
            int minZoom = 5;
            int maxZoom = 18;

            if ((zoom < minZoom || zoom > maxZoom)) {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    };

    TileOverlay tileOverlay = mGoogleMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions()
            .tileProvider(tileProvider));
}
```

Any Idea what's wrong?
Thanks and happy easter!

Comment: Its' still the same when I delete or comment out the `Toast.makeText...` parts. The `MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN` (or what ever is set) is displayed, but no overlay.

Comment: Same problem, but mine works from a local provider: `https://opencache.statkart.no/gatekeeper/gk/gk.open_gmaps?layers=topo4&zoom=$zoom&x=$x&y=$y`
but not openstreetmap, does this have anything with the 'alpha' (transparency) parameter to do ?